# Get the Latest Transaction of a Smart Contract as fast as possible

Tags: blockchain, web3.py

I need to get the latest transaction signed by a smart contract as quick as possible. How can i do that? I tried getting the last block and search all its transactions by 'from' or 'to' hashes, but it is too slow. Any way to get directly to the smart contract's transactions?

Comment: Contracts cannot sign transactions.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to run your own node, process every single `event`, and save the relevant ones into your own database then querying it through a database. It's similar to **database indexing**.

Or use APIs others have built. The Graph, Moralis, to name a few or rent a node from Quick Node.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do i need to be a validator or running a node is enough?

Comment: By the way, I tried Moralis and it also has some lag. I will look into Graph and if that does not produce good results. Unfortunately, i am building on avalanche and Quick Node does not support it. I hope i find another place to rent as I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: You could also try subscribing to the contract events via eth_subscribe through a provider (either Infura or Alchemy).

Comment: Unfortunately, they do not support Avalanche either